# React: How to store array when the page refreshes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a array in React which is to be shown using `useEffect`. That thing got from the previous component to next component. Now, I am using `useEffect` to set the array on page load using `useState`. But when I refreshes the page, the array gets undefined and the page goes blank. How to get the array again, so that it never throws me error even if I reload the page.

I have used `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`. But nothing is working out for me.

This is the code I have done so far:

```
const location = useLocation();
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(location.groupsname);
        sessionStorage.setItem('groups', JSON.stringify(location.groupsname));
        const a = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('groups'));
        console.log(a);
        setimportedgroups(a);
    }, []);
```

How should I resolve that?. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

You are close. The issue here is that you are wiping out any saved storage value when the component mounts again.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // setting storage is synchronous
  sessionStorage.setItem('groups', JSON.stringify(location.groupsname));
  // getting the value just set
  const a = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('groups'));
  console.log(a);
  setimportedgroups(a);
}, []);
```

If, upon page reload, `location.groupsname` is undefined then this is what is stored and loaded back from storage.

## Solution

You'll want to use a state initializer function and two `useEffect` hooks, 1 to persist to storage local state when it updates, and a second to update local state when the location `groupsname` updates and has a defined value.

```
const location = useLocation();

// initialize state from storage on mount
const [importedGroups, setImportedGroups] = useState(() => {
  const groups = sessionStorage.getItem('groups');
  return JSON.parse(groups) ?? {};
});

// persist importedGroups state to storage
useEffect(() => {
  sessionStorage.setItem('groups', JSON.stringify(importedGroups));
}, [importedGroups]);

// update local state when location.groupsname updates
useEffect(() => {
  if (location.groupsname) {
    setImportedGroups(location.groupsname);
  }
}, [location.groupsname]);
```

Comment: It is working. But the issue now is that, when I refreshes the page, the groups in `sessionStorage` gets emptied like this `[]`. How to overcome this?

Comment: @progpro I see. I realized that you could simply read the storage and return some initial state, and that if `location.groupsname` is undefined then that will update the state and then get persisted, so you'll need to do a check that it's defined first before updating state. Sorry for confusion, please check updated answer.